# Cant Log in but have the right password

Tags: login, password, login-screen

Whenever I want to log in, I can't get any further than the login window. I have already reset my password and changed but that also brings nothing. How can I log in again now?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release, nor if you're asking about a desktop or server. If you're asking about a desktop and it's a GUI login, if insufficient space exists in $HOME or your user directory (ie. free space), a GUI/desktop login will fail. However text logins will work, allowing you to explore space (`df`) and correct the space condition.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot back in the hard drive (looping login) version of Lubuntu. Rather than attempting to log in, press CTRL + ALT + F1 to enter the terminal screen. It should be able to log in there without a problem.